# how to use getSession Method of openmeeting SOAP?

Tags: java, jsp, openmeetings

hello I have create my web page and i create web service in it. i want to use `getSession` and loginuser method of Openmeeting SOAP .I have add successfully but when i run my web page,i can not get result.i just get output like below

```
javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement@1f16ecc Result = -35
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an error code of the login method.
You need to login using a user of type admin or web-service level. An usual user will not work.